# ODBC driver inserted from registry key does not show up in Source Administration

Tags: windows, windows-10, odbc

I have exported an existing PostgreSQL ODBC driver **(64 bit)** entry from the registry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI`

And modified the name of the driver name.

The original was

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)]
"APILevel"="1"
"ConnectFunctions"="YYN"
"Driver"="C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\psqlODBC\\bin\\psqlodbc30a.dll"
"DriverODBCVer"="13.00.0000"
"FileUsage"="0"
"Setup"="C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\psqlODBC\\bin\\psqlodbc30a.dll"
"SQLLevel"="1"
```

and my modified driver is

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)]
"APILevel"="1"
"ConnectFunctions"="YYN"
"Driver"="C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\psqlODBC\\bin\\psqlodbc30a.dll"
"DriverODBCVer"="13.00.0000"
"FileUsage"="0"
"Setup"="C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\psqlODBC\\bin\\psqlodbc30a.dll"
"SQLLevel"="1"
```

**Only the driver name has changed.**

The driver is used mostly from Python applications where I establish an DB connection. Using the modified entry **the connection can be established.**

But for some reason the created driver name is not shown in the data source administration.

[image: odbc]

Is there something I have forgotten? It works but the entry should be displayed if possible.

Comment: is it ODBC 32 bit or ODBC 64 bit?

Comment: @golimar 64 bit. Sorry, I have forgotten that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem. Additionally to the driver itself there is a directory `ODBC Drivers` containing each driver with value set to `Installed`.

After adding this my driver is shown in the administration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Data Sources
```

needs an entry in the Form:

```
"ConnectionName"="Driver"
```

Comment: As far as I understand this is the case for DSN entries. But I am not creating a DSN entry but a driver entry.